# Two popup closes at the sime time on React UseEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have the following code and have 2 popup window in the main component. I'm opening a popup out of another popup when I press ESC it shut downs 2 windows of them. How can I able to just shut down only one component and other remains still open?

Note: isOpen is a boolean type and opens popup

```
function escHandler (event: KeyboardEvent) {
   if (event.key === 'Escape') closePopup()
}

useEffect(() => {
   //
   // Escape key handling
   //
   if(isOpen && closePopupByClickingOutside) window.addEventListener('keydown', escHandler)

   return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', escHandler)
   }
}, [ isOpen ])
```

**closePopup**

```
export interface OpenClosePopupProps {
    isOpen: boolean;
    closePopup: () => void;
}

<div className="close-popup" onClick={() => closePopup()}></div>
```

Comment: Can you add the source of the `closePopup` method to your question, as well?

Comment: @Donut sorry for lacking of information. I added `closePopup`

Comment: Well, attach the event listeners to their respective popup roots, not to window.

Comment: You probably want to use a stack to track which popup is at the top.